while using aggregate plugin in logstash script i am getting undefined local variable or method 'map'
i am using aggregate plugin to keep count of how many events happened for a particular task id but when i try to use the map values inside the timeout_code i am getting "undefined local variable or method 'map'"
below is the filter code ultimately i want to send the event_count value to kafka output
aggregate {
    task_id => "%{project_id}-%{enr_subscription_id}-%{asset_id}"
    code => "
      map['event_count'] ||= 0
      map['event_count'] += 1
      map['timestamp'] = event.get('@timestamp')
    "
    push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
    timeout => 60  # Set timeout to 1 minute
    timeout_tags => ['_aggregatetimeout']
    timeout_code => "
      event.set('kafka_map', {
        'event_count' => map['event_count'],
        'timestamp' => map['timestamp'],
        'project_id' => event.get('project_id'),
        'enr_subscription_id' => event.get('enr_subscription_id'),
        'asset_id' => event.get('asset_id')
      })  # Include the map data in a separate field for Kafka
      map['event_count'] = 0  # Reset the counter for the next aggregation period
    "
  }

i am not getting definite solution as i don't understand how to make map global i

When you use push_map_as_event_on_timeout a new event is created using the contents of the map, and then it is passed to the timeout code. If you have an event_count entry in the map then that new event will have an event_count field which you can reference in the timeout_code using event.get("event_count").
Also, you do not need to reset event_count in the map because the map no longer exists after the timeout occurs. A new empty map will be created if needed later.

thank you, this solved that issue but i have another issue now as timeout is 60 seconds instead of getting data every minute i am getting it every 2 minutes what could be the reason for this
